# How can I change the color of certain characters using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm coding a brainfuck compiler and im having trouble updating the text color, as I want different symbols to have a different color depending on what they are. I am currently using this code but I'm having trouble when trying to change the color of both '[' and ']' symbols.

```
colormap = {']': '#a94926', '+': '#cc7832', '-': '#cc7832', '<': '#6a8759', '>': '#6a8759', ',': '#6396ba',
        '.': '#6396ba', '[': '#a94926'}

def on_key(event):
if event.char in colormap:
    event.widget.tag_add(event.char, 'insert-1c')

editor.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, padx=(1.75, 2.5), pady=(2.5, 1.75))
for c in colormap:
    editor.tag_config(c, foreground=colormap[c])

editor.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_key)
```

That's the code for the editor where the user codes, but when the user writes [ or ] it does not color it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution for my issue, ended up using pygments package to divide text into different BF characters.
I created this two new functions:

```
def colorFormat(event):
    code = editor.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    i = 1
    for line in code.splitlines():
        editor.index("%d.0" % i)
        formatLine(line=i)
        editor.update()
        i += 1


def formatLine(line=None):
    start_range = 0
    index = editor.index('insert').split('.')

    if line is None:
        line = int(index[0])

    line_text = editor.get("{}.{}".format(line, 0), "{}.end".format(line))

    for token, content in lex(line_text, BrainfuckLexer()):
        end_range = start_range + len(content)
        keySet = content[0]
        if keySet in colormap:
        editor.tag_add(keySet, '{}.{}'.format(line, start_range), '{}.{}'.format(line, end_range))
        start_range = end_range
```

And called colorFormat every time a key press is detected with:

```
editor.bind('<KeyRelease>', colorFormat)
```

With these two functions, I can also callcolorFormat each time user opens a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using a `ScrolledText` widget for `editor`
FWIW, `ttk.Entry` widgets don't seem to support `tag_add` or `tag_config`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('App')
        self.geometry('300x400')
        self.editor = ScrolledText(self)
        self.editor.pack(
            expand=True,
            fill=tk.BOTH,
            padx=(1.75, 2.5),
            pady=(2.5, 1.75),
        )
        self.colormap = {
            ']': '#a94926',
            '+': '#cc7832',
            '-': '#cc7832',
            '<': '#6a8759',
            '>': '#6a8759',
            ',': '#6396ba',
            '.': '#6396ba',
            '[': '#a94926',
        }
        for c in self.colormap:
            self.editor.tag_config(c, foreground=self.colormap[c])
    
        self.editor.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.on_key)

    def on_key(self, event):
        if event.char in self.colormap:
            event.widget.tag_add(event.char, 'insert-1c')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: FYI: This has an issue where holding a key (e.g.: `>`) until it repeats will cause only the last character in the string to be colored (on key release).

Comment: still not working for both [ and ] keys

Comment: also, could it be posible to update the color after some time without typing? maybe it's best as you could reuse it when loading a file

Comment: Could you post your complete code? I was able to get it working for all characters in the colormap, so I'm curious to see what you're doing differently (if anything). And you should be able to iterate over the contents of the entry and apply tags to it at any time

Comment: just posted the whole code as an edit

Comment: I’ll try it out if I have some time today!